# Pandas read.csv creates tuple

Tags: python, pandas, loops

Edit: A better loop at the bottom too. p is my abbreviation for pandas.

I am attempting to bring in a number of spectra, available as .csvs (without headers), merge them, and drop some columns. These spectra are initially available in a two column format:

```
col1  col2                       col1-1   col1-2   col2-1   col2-2 ... colm-1   colm-2
X1    Y1  X M spectra to make    X1-1     Y1-1      X2-1     Y2-1  ...  Xm-1    Ym-1
...   ...                                            ...
Xn    Yn                         X1-n     Y1-n      X2-n     Y2-n  ...  Xm-n    Ym-n
```

Where all Col1 are redundant. By dropping either all Col1 or all but the 1st Col1 the spectra are ready to be used in a few different tools I've built.

The problem lies in my intake loop:

```
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

mergespec=p.DataFrame()
for f in all_filenames:
    file = p.read_csv(f, header=None, names=["WVNB", "Int"]),
    filemerge = p.merge(file, mergespec, on="WVNB", how='outer')
```

**The object 'file' is returned as a tuple.** The code fails on the merge step, which is rejected because "Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a class 'tuple' was passed".

I can confirm that 'all_filenames' is populated correctly, and that read_csv works fine outside of this loop. In fact, I have a similar loop in another notebook that concatenates the spectra fine (which I use in figure generation).

Dear Readers I am very new to Python and my code if 90% script kiddy robbery. Please help me understand why my p.read_csv is returning a tuple, or how I biffed this loop. Thanks!

Edit: Malwaisen and Vishwas both answered the question on the tuple generation, which did work. It opened other problems with matching column names. *However*, after reading [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) I found a more parsimonious loop:

```
filemerge = p.concat([p.read_csv(f, header = None, names=["cm^-1", f]) for f in all_filenames], axis=1)
```

Which replaces everything from mergespec=p.Dataframe() onward. This met my objective with fewer lines. Also, since f was a column name and a filename, I used `df.columns.str.rstrip('.0.csv')` and lstrip to leave only the relevant sample ID from the filename as the column names.

Comment: can you try make change to this code and see if it works. file = p.read_csv(list (f), header=None, names=["WVNB", "Int"])

Comment: what is p here?

Answer (score 2):

You have a comma at the end of `file=...`. Python sees this as a tuple, where `file[0]` is your file and you could have `file[1]` and so on with additional commas.

Just remove that comma and you are good to go. Or if the comma is close to your heart use `file[0]` in your merge statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet and see if it works.

```
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

mergespec=p.DataFrame()
for f in all_filenames:
    file = p.read_csv(list (f), header=None, names=["WVNB", "Int"]),
    filemerge = p.merge(file, mergespec, on="WVNB", how='outer')
```